# Slashes and Backslashes in RegEx date

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
"Cheesy Dibbles\n\n\n12/31/2011\n\n0 Comments\n\nThe cheese is left unspoken."
```

and I want to remove the date

```
(dd) (/ or \) dd (/ or \) dddd 
where d denotes the max number of digits
```

However, I'm an escape slash short of a full regular expression. *

```
// var rexp = new RegExp(/\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,4}/gim); // doesn't work
var rexp = new RegExp(/\d{1,2}[/\\/]{0,1}\d{1,2}\/\d{1,4}/im);
var text = myStr.replace(rexp, "");
```

Reginald X. Pression where are you?

- (it works in http://regexr.com/)

Comment: You don't pass regular expression literals to `new RegExp()` - the constructor is only necessary when you need to build a regular expression from strings. The literal syntax (`/.../`) creates a RegExp object without any need for an explicit constructor call.

Comment: `/\d{1,2}[/\\]\d{1,2}[/\\]\d{1,4}/`

Comment: @Avinash Raj That works in regex101 but I'm getting myStr = "12/31/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
var myStr = 'Cheesy Dibbles\n\n\n12/31/2011\n\n0 Comments\n\nThe cheese is left unspoken.';
var rexp = new RegExp(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[\\\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\\\/](19|20)\d\d/im);
var text = myStr.replace(rexp, '');
```

https://regex101.com/r/uW1dE2/1

Chances of having someone write a comment in the 20th century are pretty slim, so could simplify the year component to 20\d\d.

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be,

```
var text = myStr.replace(/\b\d{1,2}([\/\\]?)\d{1,2}\1(?:\d{2}|\d{4})\b/im, "");
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vE0gT5/1)